# form_for is creating a new record but the values are blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I submit this form a new record is made but the values aren't being added. Tried a few different things but nothing is working

comments controller

```
 def report

    @report_comment = ReportComment.new
    if @report_comment.save(report_comment_params)

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

 private
  def report_comment_params
    params.require(:report_comment).permit(:guide_id, :submitted_by, :comment_id)
```

end

comments view (just the report form)

```
<% @report_comment = ReportComment.new %>
<% @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id]) %>
<% if current_user.nil?  %>
<% user_id = 0 %>
<% else %>
<% user_id = current_user.id %>
<% end %>
          <%= form_for([@report_comment], url: comments_report_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :guide_id, value: @guide.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :submitted_by, value: user_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :comment_id, value: comment.id %>

        <%= f.submit "Report" %>

    <% end %>
```

log with the params passed

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0XMjwzMlMLSwqpImXpjTRWd8yHUP/ERTkvnzd9rWIkSA94l9f9bCQdODXrC3SyvmfJjuW/N3zkp5pVZAf+0D+w==", "report_comment"=>{"guide_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "comment_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Report"}
```

Not sure why its not saving the values. I can alternatively add `@report_comment.update(guide_id: params[:report_comment][:guide_id], submitted_by: params[:report_comment][:submitted_by], comment_id: params[:report_comment][:comment_id])` under `if @report_comment.save(report_comment_params)` but that isn't ideal and not as good as just having them save straight from the form submit.

Comment: `@report_comment = ReportComment.new(report_comment_params)` will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign params to new method and then save it

```
def report
  @report_comment = ReportComment.new(report_comment_params)
  if @report_comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
   else
     render 'static_pages/home'
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks. Done it a million times but just went full retard for a bit there haha. Defiantly need some sleep

Answer (score 1):

Pass the params value to .new Instantiate method. You can't pass params to save method

```
def report
  @report_comment = ReportComment.new(report_comment_params)
  if @report_comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

or you can user create method instead of save

```
def report
  @report_comment = ReportComment.create(report_comment_params)
  if @report_comment.present?
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass params to new

```
@report_comment = ReportComment.new(report_comment_params)
if @report_comment.save

  redirect_to root_path
else
  render 'static_pages/home'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You controller is wrong, you should pass the parameter in `ReportComment.new` not in `.save`:

```
def report

  @report_comment = ReportComment.new(report_comment_params)
  if @report_comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

And much better if you add validations in your model.